# Prove that $\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{5a^2-4a+11} \le \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: derivatives, inequality

**The problem**

Given that $a+b+c=3, 
$
Prove that
\begin{align}
\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{5a^2-4a+11} \le \frac14
\end{align}

**Attempts**

So one apparent notice is that equality is achieved at $a=b=c=1$.
Now I intend to calculate the derivative of the fraction,

so

\begin{align}
(\frac{1}{5a^2-4a+11})' = \frac{-10a+4} {(5a^2-4a+11)^2}
\end{align}

which means each individual fraction achieve the highest value at $a=0,4$ instead of $1$.

In one last hope, I tried to convert $c=3-a-b$ but obviously since there's no equality at any $a=b$ (other than $1$), the scheme doesn't work.

So is there any other method I can try?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h223910 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/509580/471884

Comment: You should also clarify if $a, b, c$ are arbitrary real numbers, or assumed to be non-negative.